# Google Analytics view for a list of URLs

Tags: google-analytics, url

I have a set of URLs which all have the same pattern. Some of the URLs are for paid content while others are free.

I want to create a view in Google Anlaytics where I can get the statistics only related to the paid content URLs. I don't want to make any modifications in the URL.

Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't prepared to pattern the URLs differently, there are three main options:

- Keep a list (offline) of paid URLs, and use that to match the URLs after you download the data.
- Upload a list to Google Analytics, saying which is which (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en), and overlay your data with this, online.
- Create a custom dimension, and add it to every page, saying whether it is paid or free (although possibly in less obvious language). Further documentation here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en